# Where can I reliably find black branches?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I need black branches for a lot of things now, but they are still extremely rare to come by. Especially when compared to the equivalent black rocks. Where can I find these reliably (as in near guaranteed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a reliable method obtaining black branches or black lumber.  Their sources are all random:

- randomly spawning on the ground
- fishing and diving
- tree stumps in the Safari
- gift from your cat
- request reward from the Wheat Country vendor (black lumber)

You can save scum to make the last four methods more reliable. You'll have to save the day before the rewards change (Monday or the first day of the month) in order to scum the vendor. Once you've unlocked them as vendor request rewards (they started appearing for me on the week of the Year 2, Spring 25 [Tea Festival](http://fogu.com/sos1/events/spring-festivals.php), but that might a coincidence) that becomes your best, most dependable supply of black lumber. Many of the Wheat Country's request rewards each week will include 5 to 7 units of it. There's a good chance you'll be able to do at least some of them easily without having to resort to save scumming.

Black branches and lumber are never sold by the [carpenter](http://fogu.com/sos1/economy/carpentry-shop.php) or any of the [vendors](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o3_0kglxh_MSb1RrxYknjSKy5rth-dvH-70mok8G2HI/edit).